# Chrome is shrinking viewport when I open the web inspector

Tags: google-chrome, viewport, web-inspector

For some reason, whenever I open the web inspector in Chrome, the viewport of the browser shrinks. The only way to fix it is to close the inspector. Does anyone know how to fix this so it doesn't change the viewport size?

[image: chrome glitch]

Comment: Did you try to dock the inspector into the main window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the little gear in the lower right, turn off "Device Metrics" on the Overrides tab.

Comment: aha! I can't believe I missed that, I don't even know how it got enabled though.

Comment: i typically use it for seeing how things look on small/mobile screen. I only knew cause I had the same problem and it drove me nuts for a couple days.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the use. I think it auto-selected it because I think I changed the user agent to iOS.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII I deleted my whole history - in a doubt that I screwed up some settings. :(
there should be some notification to show such settings.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction - for me, hitting "Reset" on the Emulation tab fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to the head of the site giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

On the recent chrome builds try clicking off the "device toolbar"

[image]